# How to run a function in main void?

Tags: c++

**I am new to c++**

I want to call the fucntion i2d_nss_example_1 from the example code with the same name (i2d_nss_example_1), in the main void. I am using LPCXpresso and LPC-link2.

This is the code provided by example i2d_nss_example_1:

```
extern volatile int current_native;
extern volatile int current_picoampere;

void i2d_nss_example_1(void)
{
//! [i2d_nss_example_1]
    int i2dValue;
    int i2dNativeValue;
    Chip_IOCON_SetPinConfig(NSS_IOCON, IOCON_ANA0_4, IOCON_FUNC_1); /* Set pin function to analog */
    Chip_I2D_Init(NSS_I2D);
    Chip_I2D_Setup(NSS_I2D, I2D_SINGLE_SHOT, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_SetMuxInput(NSS_I2D, I2D_INPUT_ANA0_4);
    Chip_I2D_Start(NSS_I2D);
    while (!(Chip_I2D_ReadStatus(NSS_I2D) & I2D_STATUS_CONVERSION_DONE)) {
        ; /* wait */
    }
    i2dNativeValue = Chip_I2D_GetValue(NSS_I2D);
    i2dValue = Chip_I2D_NativeToPicoAmpere(i2dNativeValue, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_DeInit(NSS_I2D);
//! [i2d_nss_example_1]

    current_native = i2dNativeValue;
    current_picoampere = i2dValue;
}
```

I have modified it like this so that it runs in DEBUG mode: THIS CODE WORKS.

```
#include "board.h"

extern volatile int current_native;
extern volatile int current_picoampere;


int main(void)
{
    Board_Init();

    int i2dValue;
    int i2dNativeValue;
    Chip_IOCON_SetPinConfig(NSS_IOCON, IOCON_ANA0_4, IOCON_FUNC_1); /* Set pin function to analog */
    Chip_I2D_Init(NSS_I2D);
    Chip_I2D_Setup(NSS_I2D, I2D_SINGLE_SHOT, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_SetMuxInput(NSS_I2D, I2D_INPUT_ANA0_4);
    Chip_I2D_Start(NSS_I2D);

    while (!(Chip_I2D_ReadStatus(NSS_I2D) & I2D_STATUS_CONVERSION_DONE)) {
        ; /* wait */
    }
    i2dNativeValue = Chip_I2D_GetValue(NSS_I2D);
    i2dValue = Chip_I2D_NativeToPicoAmpere(i2dNativeValue, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_DeInit(NSS_I2D);



}
```

I want to extract it out so that I can call it in main with just a command (i2d_nss_example_1();). I have tried a couple of ways, but when i debug i get the errors: Undefined reference to 'current_native', Undefined reference to 'current_picoampere'

```
#include "board.h"


extern volatile int current_native;
extern volatile int current_picoampere;

static void i2d_nss_example_1(void);

static void i2d_nss_example_1(void)
{
//! [i2d_nss_example_1]
    int i2dValue;
    int i2dNativeValue;
    Chip_IOCON_SetPinConfig(NSS_IOCON, IOCON_ANA0_4, IOCON_FUNC_1); /* Set pin function to analog */
    Chip_I2D_Init(NSS_I2D);
    Chip_I2D_Setup(NSS_I2D, I2D_SINGLE_SHOT, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_SetMuxInput(NSS_I2D, I2D_INPUT_ANA0_4);
    Chip_I2D_Start(NSS_I2D);
    while (!(Chip_I2D_ReadStatus(NSS_I2D) & I2D_STATUS_CONVERSION_DONE)) {
        ; /* wait */
    }
    i2dNativeValue = Chip_I2D_GetValue(NSS_I2D);
    i2dValue = Chip_I2D_NativeToPicoAmpere(i2dNativeValue, I2D_SCALER_GAIN_10_1, I2D_CONVERTER_GAIN_HIGH, 100);
    Chip_I2D_DeInit(NSS_I2D);
//! [i2d_nss_example_1]

    current_native = i2dNativeValue;
    current_picoampere = i2dValue;
}



int main(void)
{
    Board_Init();
    i2d_nss_example_1();
}
```

Comment: Why have you declared your two global variables (`current_native` and `current_picoampere`) as `extern`? Are you expecting them to be defined elsewhere? If so where? That's the cause of the problem, but without understanding what you are trying to do it's hard to offer a solution. Notice that these two variables aren't being used in your working version. That explains the difference between the working version and the non-working version. It's got nothing to do with you moving the code to a different function.

Comment: I am trying to read resistance of a sensor using NHS3152. This was example code from NXP (the manufacturer). 

i2dNativeValue = Chip_I2D_GetValue(NSS_I2D); gets the resitance value ( i think). 


Even in my working example i use: extern volatile int current_native;
extern volatile int current_picoampere; ? How do i modify it

Comment: In the working version you only have the decalrations, you don't have this `current_native = i2dNativeValue; current_picoampere = i2dValue;`

Comment: Ok, i see. If i want to store the values in current_picoampere like they suggest, how should i modify the code?

Comment: What your code says is that there are two variables which are used in this code, but defined somewhere else. What your error message says is that you haven't provided the definitions for those variables. It probably means that you need to *link* your code with a library provided by the manufacturer. But how you do that I'm not sure without knowing anything about your platform or about this system.

Comment: I don't think the code needs to be modified, you need to change the way you build the code, see previous comment. Unfortunately unless someone who knows this system happens to read this post I think you are just going to have to consult the manufacturers documentation.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes sense.